# Where is [ScriptIgnore] in dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core

I'm converting a big repo over to .net core and I'm having trouble finding a replacement for the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute that used to be inside `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Is there a substitue for this attribute?

Comment: Since JavaScriptSerializer is not in .NET core, this attribute is not either. Why do you need it since you cannot use JavaScriptSerializer anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1), or (depending on your version of .NET) Newtonsoft's [`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm). `[ScriptIgnore]` (and the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace) was discontinued in .NET Core and should only be used in legacy versions of .NET Framework.

According to the docs, `System.Text.Json` *should* be compatible with all versions of .NET after .NET Framework 4.7.2 (I haven't tested this):

> For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, use the APIs in the [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8) namespace for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). This type was intended to provide serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.